Are the parts of the statment that are in italics adverbial phrases of condition, if not, what are they?
I have a struggle with the sentence

These mountains are red at this distance at this light',

as I have tried to identify the grammatical function of the italic part of the sentence. My best opinion so far has been that they present adverbial phrases of condition, for they, I think, specify physical conditions under or at which the mountains are red. As I see it they reply to the question when, in the sense, in what case or under what conditions are the mountains red? However, I could not find in the Internet any support to this opinion, so I have addressed you with the question.

What do you make of the predicate "are red"?

@TimR Actually, there should be 'are red-looking.'

The sentence doesn't seem to be idiomatic.  Where did you find this?  I suspect it wasn't written by a native English speaker.  We never say "at this light".   Also to say the mountains are red, seems odd. Also there's a missing comma. I'd suggest: "The mountains appear red at this distance, in this light".

@Billy Kerr You are partly right. The author is P.F. Strawson. The original reads as 'These mountains are red-looking at this distance in this light; blue-looking at that distance at that light';

@Giorgi There's clearly a bit of creativity going on there. He seems to be playing with the sound of the words by repeating "at that" twice, presumably for effect or even humorously.  It's not the normal way to phrase this.

They are prepositional phrases supplying supplementary conditions under which the mountains appear red.
There is a vantage point implicit in the utterance, and those conditions are anchored in that fact, even though it is not mentioned except indirectly by those prepositional phrases (which have "this" distance and light).
What is odd about the sentence is that the speaker is obviously aware of how light works, yet uses the crude verb "are" which ignores those phenomena. You would expect the verb "seem" or "appear", which would draw attention to the perception of light.

Do they have some classification name? In my text I missed that the original looks this way 'These mountains are red-looking at this distance in this light'.

It's possible somebody has given such prepositional phrases a name to refer to their function of providing information that supplements the predicate "are red-looking".   I doubt, however, that it would be "adverbial" since that's what it would have been called in the 20th century and much of that terminology has been supplanted.  You should check the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (2002). As far as I know, it was not released in separate volumes; the tome is available for about $270 online.
